# py2app ImportError with watchdog

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, py2app, watchdog

I am attempting to use py2app to bundle a small Python app that I've made in Python 2.7 on Mac. My app uses the [Watchdog library](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/), which is imported at the top of my main file:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
```

When running my program, these import statements work just fine, and the program works as expected. However, after running py2app, launching the bundled application generates the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named watchdog.observers
```

At first I thought it was something to do with the `observers` module being nested inside `watchdog`, but to test that, I added the line

```
import watchdog
```

to the top of my program, and then upon running the app, got the error

```
ImportError: No module named watchdog
```

so it seems that it actually can't find the `watchdog` package, for some reason.

I tried manually adding the `watchdog` package using py2app's `--packages` option:

```
$ python setup.py py2app --packages watchdog
```

but it had no effect.

My unbundled Python program runs just fine from the command line; other downloaded modules I've imported are giving no errors; and I have successfully bundled a simple "Hello World!" app using py2app, so I believe my setup is correct.

But I'm kind of out of ideas for how to get py2app to find the `watchdog` package. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the text of my `setup.py`, as generated by py2applet. I haven't modified it.

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['watcher.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: What does your setup.py look like?

Comment: My setup.py is just the default file generated by py2applet -- I haven't modified it at all. I've added the text to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually including the desired packages in the setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['watcher.py']
DATA_FILES = []
PKGS = ['watchdog', /*whatever other packages you want to include*/]
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'packages' : PKGS,
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had installed watchdog 0.5.4, a very old version as it turns out, and got the same error. The error was fixed after upgrading it to 0.8.3:

```
pip install watchdog --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem generally indicates that the package (in your case "watchdog", or one of its dependencies) isn't installed, or at least not in a location that py2app expects to find packages.

Do you use the same python command for running py2app as for running the script from the command-line? What is the message of the ImportError you're getting (both when importing "watchdog" and importing "watchdog.observers"?

The (way too long) output of py2app should also mention that it cannot find some packages, and which ones.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in one of the answers py2app does not seem to search the same set of paths that are used by the python interpreter, so you need to copy the python library to one of those locations.

For example I've got the MacPorts version of Python installed and found that when I had a module installed in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ py2app wasn't finding it, but it would find it when I copied it into /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages. So to copy it over run :

```
sudo cp /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/thatmodule.so /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Then run the py2applet script again and build the app to check. If it's elsewhere you can do a search for all `site-packages` locations using Spotlight's command line interface:

```
mdfind -name site-packages
```